# http request returning 503

Tags: http, go

Why does a http request in Go return

```
<html><body><h1>503</h1></body></html>
```

but I can curl the url/data without any problem.
e.g. curl https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch

example bit of code:

```
func main() {
    url := "https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch"
    data := DownloadData(url)
    fmt.Println(data)
}

func DownloadData(url string) string {
    response, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    dir := string(data)

    return dir
}
```

Comment: 503 is a fine status code. It is at the sole discretion of the server to decide which status code to send.

Comment: i understand that. i'm new to GO and was wondering why i can curl/wget the data from the url but get a 503 when doing it in GO.

Comment: Short answer: Becuase the Go code and your curl command do different things. Long answer: We can't tell you, if you don't show us the curl command that you claim works.

Comment: the curl command is just - curl https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch

Comment: I looked into this for you, curl adds 2 headers one (or both) of which the website requires in order to serve the HTML. you can find the headers with `curl -v https://.....` but they are a `User-Agent` and an `Accept` header. Adding both of these to your go code (look up how to add headers to an http request) solves your problem.

Comment: thank you, i didn't realise curl did this automatically in the back ground. thanks for your help, definitely learnt a lot http requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So elastic.co probably is checking user agent to stop the scrapers from scraping their site.Once there is no user agent header or header imply that you are automating the traffic, their bot detection system is kicking in and you are getting 503. Below your code with the example using Firefox user agent. Once you run it you'll get the body like with curl.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    url := "https://elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch,"
    data := DownloadData(url)
    fmt.Println(data)

}

func DownloadData(url string) string {

    client := &http.Client{}
    request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    request.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT x.y; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0")
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    dir := string(data)

    return dir
}
```

Comment: yes sorry the url i've been having trouble with is https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch, just put the example.com as a general example. i can curl/wget the data but get 503 when doing it in go

Comment: ohh i see, i didn't realise curl did this automatically. thank you for your help and teaching me more about http requests with GO.